# Google ClassRoom OAuth Integration Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-classroom

I am creating a web application with Spring Boot and JSF and my intention is to create courses in google classroom from my application.

I followed the example of Google to authenticate myself by Oauth: https://url.miapp.io/oS2mx

Implement that ClassroomQuickstart class from the example, but when you use the method getService() in my web application, it sends me in the Tomcat Embeded Console (Spring Boot) a Google URL for authenticate by myself from a browser and I can continue with the flow of my code.

In other words, authentication works in interactive mode waiting for me to authenticate from the browser so the application can continue the execution flow, I don't know what I should do so that I don't have to authenticate myself in this way, I don't know if it's the code that implements it as it is or has to do with the configuration in the google developer console.

Comment: If you want to avoid the user having to give consent to the application, you should use a Service Account, which follows a [2-legged OAuth flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) which doesn't require user interaction. If you want it to access data on behalf of users, you have to [grant it domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority). Do you think this would be appropriate for your situation?

Comment: thanks, I only want to create the course and send an invitation to the students, each one will log in from their classroom.google.com account outside of my application, really my application will only create the course and associate the students and the teacher is all I need, what way do you think I should follow to achieve this? thank you

Comment: In this case, you should use the Service Account to impersonate yourself. Could you please provide the code related to the OAuth process you're currently following and the corresponding API request?

Comment: Yes this is the code, i've implemented into spring boot + jsf app (in place of main method, there is a click listener JSF) https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/java

Comment: Hi! I posted an answer regarding this. Could you please confirm whether that solves your issue?

Answer (score 0):

## 3-legged OAuth:

You are currently following a 3-legged OAuth process, in which there are three parties involved: (#1) end-user, (#2) application and (#3) authorization server. **In this OAuth flow, users need to give explicit consent to the application through the browser via a consent screen**.

## 2-legged OAuth:

Since you want to avoid that, you should use a service account to access this application, so that **users are not directly involved and user consent is not required**. This workflow is usually called 2-legged OAuth (only the application and the authorization server are involved). See [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) for a more in-depth explanation.

Since you don't want the service account to run the application by itself, but to act on behalf of other accounts in the domain, you should **grant it domain-wide authority so that it can impersonate other accounts in the domain**.

## Workflow:

To achieve this, you have to follow these steps:

- Create a service account by following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount).
- Delegate domain-wide authority to the service account (you have to be a domain administrator to do this): this step authorizes the service account to access data on behalf of any user in the domain. Follow the steps indicated [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority).
- Once you have delegated domain-wide authority, you have to modify the code related to the building of the OAuth credentials. Use, for example, the code sample provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60114743):

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId("service-account@email-address") // Service account email
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("your-credentials.p12"))
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(ClassroomScopes.CLASSROOM_COURSES))
    .setServiceAccountUser("user@email-address") // Your email address (address of the user you want to impersonate)
    .build();
```

In this case, `user@email-address` refers to the account on behalf of which the course should be created. In order words, it will be the account that the service account should impersonate. Regarding the`P12` file, it should be downloaded from the Cloud Console, as explained [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58411). This can be done with a `JSON` file instead of `P12` (see [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#java)).

#### Reference:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)